# Explain the interchange of summation and differentiation

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

[image: Image below.]
Can someone please explain where the k disappeared and how come p is left behind. Tried analyzing in all directions... was left blank. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The step in question comes from the formula for geometric series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a r^n = \frac a{1-r}.$$

Comment: So K would be a and r would be (1-p)? I dont know how that helped. Can you pkease elaborate?

Comment: Almost: $k$ in my expression is playing the role of $n$ in yours. What I called $r$ corresponds to $1-p$ for you. My $a$ is just $1$ for you.